# Spring Boot + multi threading + handling connection pool

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I am having a `Spring-boot` application which contains following:
1. REST-API
2. One thread running from start will execute one service `BS` (background service we can say)

**Note**: `BS` have code to create **10** child thread which runs asynchronously to get things done.

**Requirement**:
1. `BS` is independent thread which will run throughout the application with main thread.
2. `Child thread` : will be created in `BS` and will get collapsed in `BS` once things done.

**Problem**: My thread `BS` needs to sleep(or you can say in `wait` state) if no work is pending and get back(`notify`) as and when work come. For this, I have used traditional way `wait...notify` but while waiting `BS` thread, the **10** child threads are executing the same code which `BS` thread is executing. I think thread pool management is not handled properly.
Help appreciate

`BS Thread` :  **ThreadPoolTaskExecutor**  &  **CommandLineRunner**  with connection pool set to 1

```
 ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();  
    executor.setCorePoolSize(1);  
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);  
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);  
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("BS Thread:");  
    executor.initialize();  
    return executor;
```

`Child Thread` :   **10** threads created using following code:

```
 ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
 for (BSChildExecutor jobs : listOfJobs) {
     service.submit(jobs);
 }  
 service.shutdown();`
```

Comment: *sleep if no work is pending*: This is *exactly* the case for using a `newSingleThreadExecutor()` and dispatching tasks to it whenever there's work to be done.

Comment: @chrylis Can't use sleep as there is no fix time when it will start running again. REST-API will trigger and then that thread will start again.  `newSingleThreadExecutor()` can you please give me example of this?

Comment: *You* are the one who used the word "sleep". The correct approach is to use a single-thread executor, which works exactly like any other executor and can only execute one task at a time serially (and then blocks the thread if it runs out of work).

Comment: @iamrajshah I think that what chrylis is telling you is that you shouldn't need to sleep or wait or anything, since a thread pool does that for you: you sbmit tasks to the pool, and it starts working on those tasks. When tasks are done, the thread pool automatically waits for the next ones, doing nothing. So the fct that you're using wait and notify is quite surprising. We can't help much without a clear problem, and the code reproducing it.

Comment: @chrylis Sorry if you misunderstood with my words, my question is `BS` will be there throughout the program and task will be there for that thread as and when required. I thought that `newSingleThreadExecutor()` will executes only once and will die if assign task is done. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @JBNizet I have share the code snippets which I have written, what else can I share so that you can get detail idea of issue.

Comment: A complete minimal program reproducing the problem (boot is irrelevant here), a description of what you expect that minimal but complete program to do, and a description of what it does instead.

Comment: @JBNizet I know (boot) is irrelevant to threading, but when the thread in `wait` state it losses the database connection established by hibernate-JPA. My question is have you understand my requirements?

Comment: Your requirements, yes, I think. Your actual problem, no. Which is why you should post a complete minimal program reproducing the problem, a description of what you expect that minimal but complete program to do, and a description of what it does instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186000/discussion-between-iamrajshah-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: Is this BS is executed periodically? How do you BS service will know there are new jobs to created and needs to be executed them?

Comment: @BhanuHoysala I have mention in my very first comment that `BS` will get trigger from REST-API.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a flaw in your design. The flow you wanted to achieve can be superly simplified.

First, you've added `BS` which is not required at all. Typical BS are processes include logging, system monitoring, scheduling, notification etc.

In your case, `BS` is inherently provided by the Thread pool.

Create a Thread pool of X size which meets your requirement which will never die till you *gracefully shut down your Spring Application*. 
Since REST API is the triggering point for your `listOfJobs` to be executed, Whenever new job(s) comes you keep submitting to the pool.

***Snippet to shutdown thread pool gracefully while gracefully shutting down Spring Application***

```
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
        this.connector.pause();
        Executor executor = this.connector.getProtocolHandler().getExecutor();
        if (executor instanceof ThreadPoolExecutor) {
            try {
                ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) executor;
                threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
                if (!threadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    log.warn("Thread pool did not shut down gracefully within "
                            + TIMEOUT + " seconds. Proceeding with forceful shutdown");

                    threadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow();

                    if (!threadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        log.error("Thread pool did not terminate");
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creating a thread pool at initial stage is not required in my case, Only single thread I want that will run parallel to main thread & will create X threads as and when required. _shut down your Spring Application_ I cannot shutdown my application, as the REST-API needs to run 24*7 and `BS` also needs to run hand in hand.

Comment: @iamrajshah 1. If you don't need thread pool initially, you can have a lazy initialization of thread pool, 2. If you are really over optimistic and your application runs 24*7 then you don't need graceful shutdown handling part. 3. What is the exact link between your API and BS   ?

Comment: link between API and BS is, web-apps is doing some operation and depends on operation REST-API gets called and there comes `BS` in picture which we do the rest of the task depend on REST-API. Coming back to your 1st question I need one thread which run with main thread throughout application (for handling `BS` part)